# Retraining a soldier in XCOM 2

Tags: xcom-2

I'm near the final mission in my Commander/Ironman campaign and I'm considering of retraining some of my soldiers. The problem is I built Advanced War Center pretty late so many of my soldiers do not have a hidden ability. My questions are:

1. **Will retraining a soldier (colonel) without a hidden ability have a chance to get it?**
2. Will it affect any bonuses already gained like extra hacking ability of specialists?
3. If a soldier being retrained possess an upgraded weapon will it be available to other soldiers while he's in AWC?
4. What happens to a PCS a soldier being retrained has?

Answer (score 5):

1. Can't say for sure, as I've always played with the retroactive awc mod, but as far as I know, retraining does not affect the awc perk, i.e. if you had one, you keep it, if you had none, you don't get one.
2. No, just resets the perks.
3. Yes, you can unequip the weapon and it's available to other soldiers.
4. Stays where it is, PCS don't have any requirement.

Comment: I believe 2-4 are correct. No idea on 1.